# Blender file confuse while use copyrighted objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, copyright-display

Hello guys first i used the copyrighted object in blender then i deleted that object and now i am going to use this blender file for commercial use. is there will be any issue while using this blender file in game which will then published on playstore.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not lawyers

Comment: copyright-display: *Legal questions about the use of copyright laws are off-topic*

Comment: Maybe you might want to ask this on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com)